# Rails: one model for multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have article model with the following attributes: article.rb

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :title, :tag_list, :type_list
 end
```

Now for creating each type of the article I want to have a different _form view with different fields.

Does it mean that I need to add new attributes to my article.rb or I have to add multiple models for my article controller for each type?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "type of article" (can you give some examples?)

Comment: It is better to add a new table "lookup_article_types", where you can set the predefined article types and use the lookup_article_type_id instead of the type_list of Article model.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel : Whenever I create an article I give a tag for each article in order to be able to filter my articles. For example, when I create an article I want to add tags like tutorial, sample and so on. Now when I am creating an article which is a tutorial, I want to have not only id, title and content, but also author and maybe other fields. 
Do I need to have all that attributes in my model? or I need to have another model for that.

Comment: So, next question is - are those extra fields type specific? Is author fields specific only to tutorial or can be optional for other post types as well?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel : yes exactly. I want to make that fields specific for each type.
Right now the fields are optional for all posts and I am using only one form and one model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering comments above I suggest you go for Single Table Inheritance.
A good tutorial on STI is here http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

Pro of this solution is that you will still be able to do `Post.all`. Con is that db table will have lots of columns, unused for most records (each record will use only type specific values filled)

If you have any questions just ask, I'll try to help :)

Comment: I have tried to follow this tutorial http://joemcglynn.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/rails-single-table-inheritance-part-2/#comment-35

but I have a problem in my create method.

Comment: here is the source code of the tutorial..https://github.com/canonical/Single-Table-Example
.in my create method I have 
 def create
    @article = Object.const_get(params[:article][:type]).new(params[:article])

and in my _form I have <%= f.hidden_field :type %>
<%= render :partial => "edit" + f.object.type.downcase, :locals=>{:f=>f} %>
and I get the following error:  undefined method `[]‘ for nil:NilClass.
I am trying to solve this problem but I can't . it seems that it doesn't inderstand param[:article]

Comment: Try `param['article']`, params hash with symbols is Rails magic and may not work in this case.

Comment: Also - if in doubt try printing params - always helps :)

Comment: this doesn't seem like the best solution. Why not have a column for articles such as `article_type` which would then link to different types which would contain info on different fields for each type

Comment: @mmcrae and how exactly do you want to achieve it in Rails? And - how is it different from STI which is widely-used mechanism to do exactly that? Rails is about not reinventing a wheel and what you propose sounds exactly like that...

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure what exactly I meant at the time. I was thinking [like this](https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/refactoring-rails-sti/). Essentially, I think it's a downside to have null columns/half-empty rows built into your data model, when you could basically just have different models/tables, with one core table linking out to these different tables. I.e. `Car` model/table, with field `car_type` which would tell you the specific table `TwoDoorCar` or `FourDoorCar` etc. which would have different fields/different number of fields. I'm a novice, idk if it makes sense, just my 2cents